# Elaboration date in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a system (in VBA for Excel) that works downloading data from web site. After collect the date I need to create a relationship using the day.
The problem in this case is the format.
[image]
In this format sum if or vlookup don't recognize the day. How can I solve it?

```
Sub Recupera_dati()
    Dim dtToday As Date
    Dim Anno As String
    Dim Url As String
    Dim sQry As String
Dim Riga2 As Integer
Riga2 = 2
        Anno = "2023"
        Mese = "Novembre"
    Url = "https://www.ilmeteo.it/portale/archivio-meteo/Momo/" & Anno & "/" & Mese
    sQry = Mese & Anno
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=sQry, Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Origine = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""" & Url & """))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
        "    Data2 = Origine{2}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
        "    #""Modificato tipo"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data2,{{""Giorno"", Int64.Type}, {""T Media"", type text}, " & _
        "{""T min"", type text}, {""T max"", type text}, {""Precip."", type text}, {""Umidit¨¤"", type text}, {""Vento Max"", type text}," & _
        " {""Raffica"", type text}, {""Fenomeni"", type text}, {""Info"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & _
        Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Modificato tipo"""
    'Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & sQry & ";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & sQry & "]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = sQry
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert
Range("A1").Value = "Data"

While Worksheets(1).Cells(Riga2, 2) <> ""
Worksheets(1).Cells(Riga2, 1) = Worksheets(1).Cells(Riga2, 2) & "/" & Mese & "/" & Anno
'Worksheets(1).Cells(Riga2, 1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
'Worksheets(1).Cells(Riga2, 1).Select
Riga2 = Riga2 + 1

Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Riga2, 1)).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

Wend


End Sub
```

Comment: imgur is blocked for me. What is in the image?

Comment: @Chill60 - dates in the format of **1/Novembre/2023**

Comment: `Worksheets(1).Cells(Riga2, 2) & "/" & Mese & "/" & Anno`: you're creating a `String` but you need to create a `Date`.

Comment: The image rappresent the format 1/November/2023, 2/Novembre/2023 ect.

Comment: Is it a case of parsing I'm assuming italian dates as text to a vba Date data type? I think the example [DateTimeParse2Example.bas](https://github.com/MarkJohnstoneGitHub/VBA-DotNetLib/blob/main/VBA/Examples/System/DateTime/Methods/DateTimeParse2Example.bas) might help.  Or could do your own italian date parsing routine.  The DateTime.ToOADate() property returns a VBA Date from a DateTime object.  Appears what ever method use probably require converting to a VBA Date.

Comment: Use [`Option Explicit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement) for VBA coding, this might help to make the datatype explicit.

Comment: @user10186832 that requires variable declaration but doesn't make the type explicit. It is still a good idea.

Comment: Custom date formatting is [here](https://software-solutions-online.com/excel-custom-formatting-month-languange/)

Comment: And [here](https://software-solutions-online.com/excel-custom-date-formatting/) is how you use Excel custom date formatting

Comment: This works  `Range("D7").NumberFormat = "[$-410]mmmm d, yyyy;@"` (but in the opposite direction)

Comment: @user10186832 I try Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Riga2, 1)).NumberFormat = "[$-410]mmmm d, yyyy;@" but is always the same

Comment: @user10186832 `NumberFormat` works when you're working with an actual date, but OP has a `String` here.

Comment: @Inuraghe you need an actual `Date`. That's your problem. You have text-that-looks-like-a-date. Formatting is not your problem.

Comment: This should work to convert an Italian date string to a date (but it doesn't on my UK machine) `=DATEVALUE(TEXT(L7,"[$-410]mmmm d, yyyy;@"))`

Comment: Test data "marzo 1, 2023"

Answer (score 0):

```
Worksheets(1).Cells(Riga2, 2) & "/" & Mese & "/" & Anno
```

is creating a `String`, when you want a `Date`:

```
Dim Riga2 As Long ' not Integer

With Worksheets(1)
    Dim UltimaRiga As Long
    UltimaRiga = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    For Riga2 = 2 To UltimaRiga
        .Cells(Riga2, 1).Value = DateValue(Mese & " " & .Cells(Riga2, 2).Value & ", " & Anno)
    Next

    .Range("A1:A" & UltimaRiga).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
End If
```

Comment: I can't use the number instead of the month name

Comment: I don't have only November in my real dataset, I would like to create an automatic soluction

Comment: Try the edited answer using `DateValue`.

Comment: @Inuraghe Aren't you getting the webiste link for the query using month name and year?  If dynamically generating the query should be able associate a month number to a list of month names and create a the Dates using DateSerial(year, month, day).  Day from each row obtianed I'm assuming.  I.e. Select from a list of months names, obtain the month number  (1-12). So inputs are month and year currently hardcoded to November, 2023.

Comment: @BigBen In this row I have a syntax error
.Cells(Riga2, 1).Value = DateValue(Mese & " " &  & .Cells(Riga2, 2).Value & ", " & Anno)

Comment: Extra `&`, sorry, removed.